# Register a new XFRM type

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel, kernel

I am working on implementing a [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5858). In short this RFC proposes a solution to compress *headers* inside an IPsec ESP packet payload.

I was going to develop a Linux kernel module. However this is impossible due to a restriction of protocol numbers in the Linux Kernel Code, see: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/xfrm/xfrm_state.c#L260

My RFC uses a custom protocol number 142 where ESP uses 50 and IPcomp uses 106. If we cannot register a custom xfrm type, what would be the solution ?

Is it conventional to make a "raw" patch?

If you have an answer, I'm interested! Thanks in advance !

Edit : Example of xml_register_type with custom protocol number

```
​
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>
    #include <linux/slab.h>
    #include <net/ip.h>
    #include <net/xfrm.h>
    #define MY_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL 142
    
    static const struct xfrm_type my_custom_xfrm_type = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,  
        .proto = MY_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL,
    };
    
    static int __init my_custom_module_init(void) {
        int err = xfrm_register_type(&my_custom_xfrm_type, AF_INET);
    
        if(err < 0)
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Can't add type");
        }
        else
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Added type");
        }
    
        return err;
    }
    
    static void __exit my_custom_module_exit(void) {
    
        xfrm_unregister_type(&my_custom_xfrm_type, AF_INET);
    
    }
    
    
    module_init(my_custom_module_init);
    module_exit(my_custom_module_exit);
    
    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
    MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
    MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Custom XFRM Module");
```

Output :

​ `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./custom_type.ko: Protocol not supported ​`

Comment: Protocol numbers are controlled by [IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority)](https://www.iana.org/). Anyone can try to register a protocol number.

Comment: In this RFC, IANA has allocated the value 142 to "ROHC". My point is that the Linux Kernel seems to prevent the use of `xfrm_register_type(142, AF_INET)` in a C kernel module.

Comment: "_In short this RFC proposes a solution to compress a payload inside an IPsec EPS packet._ That RFC is about header compression, not payload compression; it compresses the inner headers of IP packets. That reduces the overhead of IPSec, not the payload of IPSec.

Comment: This RFC is about the use of the header compression technique called ROHC inside the payload of IPsec packets. It reduces the headers of protocol encapsulations inside a EPS payload. So, in short, yes, it compress the payload of the EPS packet. Really, thanks for your interest but that's a bit off the topic :'(